# Java find weekdays for a given date

Tags: java

i need to find weekdays for a given date.
The given date is = 2080-03-20
Now i need to find a weekday after 5 days from the given date.

It should return: 
2080-03-25

I tried this:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util;

Date date=new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
date = calendar.getTime()
SimpleDateFormat s
s= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
Date today = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatedDate = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd")
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 21916);
String after60years = (String)(formattedDate.format(c.getTime()))
int days = 5;
for (int i=0;i<days;)
{
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)<-5)
{
i++;
}
}
date = calendar.getTime();
s=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy=MM-dd");
System.println(s.format(date+21916));
```

It returns:
2080-03-19
2080-03-26

Is this solution is correct ?
Will it return always weekday after 5 days from the given date.
Any help, thank you

Comment: Somewhat unrelated: I recommend using the [`java.time` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) added in Java 8.

Comment: i made a mistake in my code, i found the way but im not sure, i just need guidance

Comment: You need to drop `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` immediately and start using the newer Java Date and Time API.

Comment: That code is so full of errors, unnecessary code, and bad formatting that it's somewhat difficult to understand what you intended. Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.now(
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
)
.plusDays( 5 )
.with(
    org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDayOrSame()
)
```

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `TemporalAdjuster`

Apparently you want to move a certain number of days into the future, but not counting weekend days of Saturday and Sunday.

In *java.time*, we move to another date by way of a `TemporalAdjuster`.

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

Your could write your own adjuster for skipping the weekend.

### `nextWorkingDay`

But no need, we have an implementation available to us in the *ThreeTen-Extra* library: [`org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#nextWorkingDay())

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay() ;
```

Use that adjuster in a loop for your count of days.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;
LocalDate date = today ;
int daysAhead = 5 ;
List< LocalDate > dates = new ArrayList<>( daysAhead ) ;
for( int i = 1 ; i <= daysAhead ; i ++ ) 
{
    date = date.with( ta ) ;
    dates.add( date ) ;
}
```

### `nextWorkingDayOrSame`

If by your Question you meant skip five days later, then determine if that date is a weekday, if not move to the next weekday, then we use the temporal adjuster `nextWorkingDayOrSame`.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ) ;
int daysAhead = 5 ;
LocalDate later = today.plusDays( daysAhead ) ;
LocalDate date = later.with( org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDayOrSame() ) ;
```

Comment: Question is asking to *"find a weekday after 5 days from the given date"*, not "find date 5 weekdays after the given date". Example in question is `2080-03-20` (Wednesday), with expected output of `2080-03-25` (Monday). The current code in the answer would result in `2080-03-27` (Wednesday).

Comment: @Andreas That interpretation contradicts the title and first sentence. But, very well, I added code at top and bottom of the Answer for that problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using `java.time`:

```java
public LocalDate weekdayAfter5Days(LocalDate date) {
    var target = date.plusDays(5);
    var weekday = target.getDayOfWeek();
    if (weekday == DayOfWeek.SATURDAY || weekday == DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
        var nextMonday = TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
        target = target.with(nextMonday);
    }
    return target;
}
```

If date is given as  a string with format `yyyy-MM-dd` just create a `LocalDate`:

```java
var date = LocalDate.parse(text);
```

or, for a different format (e.g. `dd/MM/yyyy`):

```java
var date = LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: Which part of this code will "find a weekday", i.e. ensure the date is not a weekend day (Saturday or Sunday)?

Comment: Code has very large overhead. To fix: 1) Instead of `DayOfWeek.from(target)`, use `target.getDayOfWeek()`. --- 2) Instead of creating a `TemporalAdjuster`, write `if (SATURDAY) { add 2 days } else if (SUNDAY) { add 1 day }`.

Answer (score -1):

`Java8` provides `java.time` library with rich features. You may try the following sample code.

```
public class TimeTest {

   private static TemporalAdjuster TEMPORAL_ADJUSTER = TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
   private static List<DayOfWeek> OFF_DAYS = Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2080-03-20");

    long daysToPlus = 5l;
    for (int day = 1; day <= daysToPlus; day++) {

        localDate = localDate.plusDays(1);
        if (OFF_DAYS.contains(localDate.getDayOfWeek())) {
            localDate = localDate.with(TEMPORAL_ADJUSTER);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(localDate);
    System.out.println(localDate.getDayOfWeek());
  }
}
```

Comment: Why have `dtf`? `LocalDate.parse("2080-03-20")` without a `DateTimeFormatter` will parse ok. --- Which part of this code will "find a weekday", i.e. ensure the date is not a weekend day (Saturday or Sunday)?

Comment: Thansks a lot Tayyab Razaq. if i need to exclude holidays then how i can i do

Comment: @psLaVerriere Do you have a list of Holidays somewhere?

Comment: yes Andreas, these are holidays: 2080-12-31
2080-04-04
2080-04-06
2080-05-11
2080-05-19
2080-06-15
2080-06-30
2080-08-04
2080-09-01
2080-11-10
2080-12-24
2080-12-25

Comment: Thank you Basil Bourque

Comment: it wont work with a list of holidays because if run the code next year, then the year will be 2081 then holidays wont be the same.

Comment: @psLaVerriere If you don't know the holidays for 2081, how would you expect the code to skip them?

Comment: No Andreas you are right., The code will be fine for this year. Maybe i can add holidays for some years in advance. like 2081, 2082...for 10 years from 2080....But thank you for you all. if you can help to exclude holidays for 2080 it would be nice , i will continue then...

Comment: @psLaVerriere Since your question didn't say anything about holidays, I suggest you create a new question and ask about that. Remember to include description of which holidays you want, though you should probably make that configurable in your program, so the list of holidays can be updated as needed, without having to rebuild and redeploy the code.

Comment: OK Andreas so we can close this thread. Thanks to all of you. It was very helpful for me.

Comment: @Andreas you're right, we don't need `dtf`, we can use overloaded parse function without `dtf`. It was used in the question, so I continued it.

Comment: Guys updated the code as per your comments, Please check and give your valuable feedback